# Duplicate values of columns in a tab delimited file

Tags: python, shell, awk

I would like to duplicate the values that are separated by `|`, transforming them into new columns.

The following subset example file would be:

```
1_A 2_A 3_A
1|0 0|0 0|0
0|0 0|0 1|1
1|1 1|0 1|0
0|1 1|1 0|0
0|1 1|0 0|0
0|0 0|0 0|0
0|1 1|1 0|1
0|0 0|0 1|0
1|1 1|0 0|1
0|0 0|0 0|0
```

The desired format would be:

```
1_A 1_B 2_A 2_B 3_A 3_B
1|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|1 1|1
1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 1|1 0|0
0|0 1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 0|0
0|0 1|1 1|1 0|0 0|0 0|0
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
0|0 1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 1|1
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|1 0|0
1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 0|0 1|1
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
```

On the example above, the 1_B sample is the duplicate values to the right of the pipe character from the 1_A sample.

Thanks for any lead.

Comment: Why `1_A` has this `1|1` in the output (first row).

Comment: Hi Daniel. That's because it duplicates the value on the left of the pipe character.
I think I forgot to mention that the duplicate values are from the numbers on the right and left of the pipe.

Comment: What is more preferable for you: Python or Awk approach? (in terms of further usage)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest honestly awk...

Comment: @guidebortoli, If you feel you would discard/ignore Python approaches, perhaps, the tag could be removed from the question (due to intention of further usage)

Comment: Also, let's consider that number of columns is dynamic (could be more that 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                {t=$i; 
                 sub("A","B",$i); 
                 printf "%s %s ",t,$i} 
              print ""; next}
             {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                {split($i,a,"|"); 
                 printf "%s %s ",a[1]"|"a[1],a[2]"|"a[2]} 
              print ""}' file

1_A 1_B 2_A 2_B 3_A 3_B
1|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|1 1|1 
1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 1|1 0|0 
0|0 1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 0|0 
0|0 1|1 1|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 
0|0 1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 1|1 
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|1 0|0 
1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 0|0 1|1 
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
```

Comment: This is outrageously impressive.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F"[ |]" '
FNR==1{
  print $1,"1_B",$2,"2_B",$3,"3_B"
  next
}
FNR>1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     $i=$i "|" $i
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk -F"[ |]" '                         ##Setting field separator eiter space or pipe here.
FNR==1{                                ##Checking condition if this is first line.
  print $1,"1_B",$2,"2_B",$3,"3_B"     ##Printing headers as per OP.
  next                                 ##Using next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                      ##Closing FNR==1 condition BLOCK here.
FNR>1{                                 ##Checking condition if FNR>1 then do following.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                  ##Starting a for loop from i=1 to till value of NF(number of fields in current line).
     $i=$i "|" $i                      ##Setting value of current field to current field |(pipe) current field value here.
  }                                    ##Closing BLOCK for for loop here.
}                                      ##Closing BLOCK for FNR>1 condition here.
1                                      ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited current line here.
'  Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file(which we need to process here).
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1_A 1_B 2_A 2_B 3_A 3_B
1|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|1 1|1
1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 1|1 0|0
0|0 1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 0|0
0|0 1|1 1|1 0|0 0|0 0|0
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
0|0 1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 1|1
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|1 0|0
1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 0|0 1|1
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
```

Comment: Tight and simple, gotta <3 it.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another in awk:

```
$ awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if(NR==1)
            sub(/A/,"& " i "_B",$i)
        else {
            t=$i
            sub(/\|/," ",t)
            sub(/\|/,"|"t"|",$i)
        }
}1' file
```

`head -3` of output:

```
1_A 1_B 2_A 2_B 3_A 3_B
1|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|1 1|1
...
```

And one in `sed`:

```
$ sed '1s/\(._\)A/\1A \1B/g; s/\([01]\)|\([01]\)/\1|\1 \2|\2/g' file
```

Output:

```
1_A 1_B 2_A 2_B 3_A 3_B
1|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|1 1|1
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def split_values(s):
    # split the string over '|', and format each to the expected output
    return [*map(lambda _: f"{_}|{_}", s.split('|'))]

# list of dataframes which we will later concat over
tmp_df_lst = []
for col in df.columns:
    # apply split_values over each column
    tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(df[col].apply(split_values).values.tolist(), 
                 columns=[f"{col[:-1]}A", f"{col[:-1]}B"])
    tmp_df_lst.append(tmp_df)

# result
pd.concat(tmp_df_lst, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    1_A 1_B 2_A 2_B 3_A 3_B
0   1|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
1   0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|1 1|1
2   1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 1|1 0|0
3   0|0 1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 0|0
4   0|0 1|1 1|1 0|0 0|0 0|0
5   0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
6   0|0 1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 1|1
7   0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|1 0|0
8   1|1 1|1 1|1 0|0 0|0 1|1
9   0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
```